# How to to insert floats into mysql and then query eqality

Tags: mysql, floating-point

Wowee ..does mysql work with floats or not!

1) I insert a float into mysql field
   price =  0.1

2) I run the below query:

```
select * from buy_test where price = 0.1
```

WOW!  I get no results

3) I run the below query:

```
select * from buy_test where price < 0.1 

I get no results
```

4) I run the below query

```
 select * from buy_test where price > 0.1
```

YAY!  I get results but no..I wanted where price =0.1

How to I insert a float to mysql so I can query a float in mysql

Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE `buy_test` (
  `user_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `insert_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Comment: Can you show buy_test structure ?

Comment: @VigneshKumar has answered you

Answer (score 2):

That's because 0.1 doesn't exist in floating point arithmetic.
It would take an infinity number of digits to print the real value of 0.1 in binary (just like it would take an infinity number of digits do print the real value of 10/3).

In your table, you are storing the price with a 'float' type, which is represented on 32 bits. The value 0.1 is rounded to 0.100000001490116119384765625 (which is the nearest representation of 0.1 in the float type format).

When you are requesting all rows where prices are equal to 0.1, I strongly suspect the interpreter to use the double type, or at least, a more precise type than float.
But let's consider it's using the double type on 64 bits.
In the double type, 0.1 is rounded to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 .

When the engines makes the comparison, it leads to:

```
if (0.100000001490116119384765625 ==
    0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625) ...
```

which is obviously false. But it's true for operator > .

I'm pretty sure that this where clause would work: "where price = 0.100000001490116119384765625"

By the way, when the result of your query tells you that the price is "0.1", it's a lie. The value is rounded to be "beautifully displayed".

There is no real solution to your problem, everybody knowing floating point arithmetic problems will discourage you to use equality comparison on floats.
You may use an epsilon for your request.

There is a very interesting article named "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"; you can find it there:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: oups, I didn't see this question was so old